# ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'imgs_info.file_name' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, aws

Tengo una base de datos MySQL con dos tablas, una tabla **imgs_info** y otra tabla **img_annotator_relation**. Para mi desarrollo estoy usando una base de datos en local que gestiono a través de MySQL Workbench y en producción tengo una MySQL de AWS. Las dos bases de datos tienen los mismos datos y la misma estructura pero por alguna razón, la misma query me funciona en la base de datos local y no en la de producción.

La query es la siguiente:

```
SELECT 
    img_id, dataset, city, file_name 
FROM 
   imgs_info 
WHERE 
   dataset='citypersons' 
AND persons_annotated=0 
AND NOT (
    SELECT 
       COUNT(*) 
    FROM img_annotator_relation 
    WHERE img_annotator_relation.img_name=imgs_info.file_name 
    AND user_name='admin' 
    AND ds_type='persons'
) > 0 
AND discarded_by_user IS NOT TRUE 
AND auto_discarded IS NOT TRUE 
AND is_key_frame=1;
```

El error que me da aparentemente es porque no encuentra la columna "file_name" en la tabla "imgs_info", pero entonces no entiendo porque en la base de datos local si que me funciona esa query.

Para más inri, he probado reduciendo la query a:

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(*) 
FROM 
   img_annotator_relation 
WHERE img_annotator_relation.img_name=imgs_info.file_name;
```

Y no me funciona en ninguna de las dos bases de datos, me da el mismo error.

Si alguien me puede ayudar, lo agradecería.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira solo analicemos la segunda.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM img_annotator_relation 
WHERE img_annotator_relation.img_name = imgs_info.file_name;
```

cuenta todo de `img_annotator_relation`
donde el nombre de imagen sea igual al nombre de imagen... pero de otra tabla ??

Para poder consultar 2 tablas, tienes que unirlas de alguna forma. Para esto debes usar JOIN. Además recomiendo el uso de alias, para no escribir toda la tabla siempre.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM img_annotator_relation iar
JOIN imgs_info ii ON ii.alguna_pk = iar.alguna_pk
WHERE iar.img_name = ii.file_name;
```

Entonces nuestra consulta nos queda como:
contamos todo de `iar` unido con `ii` a partir de sus PK
contamos aquellas en donde el `name` sea igual.

Comment: Tienes razón, debería usar JOIN para ser más correcto. De todas formas, la razón por la que había discrepancia entre MySQL workbench y el MySQL de producción, es porque realmente no me dí cuenta y estaba probando dos cosas diferentes. Mi problema ya está resuelto, muchas gracias por tu ayuda ;)